# Disabling LED breathing effect on a plug and play gaming mouse

Tags: hardware, mouse

I currently own a plug and play gaming mouse, which has 7 LED colors which keep on cycling automatically in a slow breathing effect. The mouse is "Magic Eagle by Havit". There were no drivers that came along with the mouse, nor are there any on their website. Is there any way of freezing it on any single color? Any software that may be able to do that?

Comment: Do you have the model number for your mouse? There are multiple Magic Eagle mice by Havit.

Comment: Its MS672. And no there are no drivers for that model on their site!

Answer (score 1):

The answer will depend on the model of your mouse.

In the Magic Eagle gaming mice series, there are multiple mice that have the LED lighting effect. The [HV-MS727](http://havit.hk/products/havithv-ms727-professional-gaming-mouse/) has the LED controls are the bottom of the mouse while mice like the [HV-765](http://havit.hk/products/havithv-ms765-gaming-mouse/) do not have LED controls.

Like you mentioned, it is a plug and play mouse and does not require a driver. Check the [drivers](http://havit.hk/support/downloads/) page to make sure your model is not included. If it is not, your best bet would be to directly contact Havit support at `support@prohavit.com`.